# Ruby on Rails: How to add parameter to database in existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, rails-console

I built a model using rails g model name:string, description:text, price:float, and finished my project, but now want to add more parameters to the model. Instead of starting over, how can I add more parameters? Is there a method to do so within the rails console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rails generate migration AddColumnToTable column:datatype
```

so if you wanted to add a `name` column to a `people` table it might look like:

```
rails generate migration AddNameToPeople name:string
```

then run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Sometimes if I forget a column I'll rake db:rollback which rolls back 1 migration, then I'll update the migration file in the db directory, save the file, then rake db:migrate

Comment: I agree do a rollback, no reason to add a bunch of migration files in the beginning of a project. Hard to keep your migrations clean just to add one column